# What does the notation $C(\mathbb{R})$ mean?

Tags: notation, continuity

I thought that $C(\mathbb{R})$ was the set of all $$\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
functions that are continuous, but I may of seen a case that the function
was $$\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$$

Was the use of $C(\mathbb{R})$ correct there, or was it a mistake
?

Comment: I think it's just a simple matter of definition. The most common one is, I believe, the first one: $\,C(X)$= the space of all *real-valued* continuous functions on $\,X\,$ .

Comment: $C(X,Y)$ is the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$, and if $X=Y$, you can write $C(X)$ instead of $C(X,X)$

Comment: A word of caution on that; if $M$ is a real manifold, then $C(M)$ typically means $C(M,\mathbb{R})$ rather than $C(M,M)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that are continuous in every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
It would be best to denote it as $C^0(\mathbb{R})$, motivated by the definition 
$$
C^r(\mathbb{R})=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}|f \text{ is of class }C^r\}
$$
for $r\geq 0$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd imagine it's because your answer presents a single definition as ***the*** definition of the notation "$C(\mathbb{R})$", when in fact there are many *distinct*, common uses for the notation $C(\mathbb{R})$. In other words, there's no right answer. I for one have seen $C(X)$ used to mean the space of continuous functions $X\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Hmmm, was looking at some of my past downvotes and I downvoted this, although I don't recall doing so. Might have just been a miscue on my part.